# How to integrate dao in my Java Project

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, dao

I am working to complete an assignment to integrate dao Support in my website. I have completed most of the part of creating separate dao for each table an integrating create/update/inset/delete functionality in them. I have some additional questions. I will be extremely grateful if you can point me to some resources as I am confused after reading many tutorials:

1. How to i create connection manager. So that I have single connections for each dbo and what is the best design to implement it. Should I put the Connection object in daoManager or create a separate singleton class for that and keep an object.
2. Once I have the Dao ready, how do I manage complex operation like join from my controller as each dao fetched object/data from their corresponding table. Do I need to join the output in my controller.

Please pardon me if this doesn't make sense. I can add additional information if required.

Comment: Just to note: connections tend to be bound to a client thread, not to a class. If there are 5 users, there are 5 concurrent connections which are perhaps used by the same database classes. In a multi user environment such as a website, thinking in singletons generally leads to misery. Look into datasources and connection pools before you make design decisions.

Comment: I will suggest going through examples. on this. And about join You can define the joins on entities or execute them via queries. Do it based on your usage.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks like spring mvc, struts2 or plain jsp servlet?

Comment: Hi Ranjit, I am using mvc design but not using any framework. Which framework would you recommend. I will go ahead and explore the options.